# MySQL Workbench Forward Engineer from only the current diagram

Tags: schema, mysql-workbench, database-diagrams

I want to create a test database from a huge schema in MySQL, but when I try to do Forward Engineer from a Diagram with about 6 tables, it try to create all the tables, views and routines groups that I have in the schema.

I'm dealing with more than 100 tables and it is really annoying to have to select the tables of the diagram you are working on.

Is there an automatic way to do that instead of selecting one by one the tables I want?

Comment: Same question as a few days before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349086/mysql-workbench-forward-engineer-from-only-the-current-diagram. Same answer.